# Is this a common Folder structure for a Node.js project?

Tags: node.js

I am continuing on a project that someone else started it before, and I was still a beginner in nodejs when i first started with him, but  after acquiring some experience and seen enough tutorials, I am finding his project's folder structure a bit strange, I haven't seen anything like it in the online tutorials.

Is the below a common practice in node.js projects, and if yes, why the root project folder is inside a folder named node_modules? node_modules is usually for storing the npm packages.

```
 └───node
        └───node_modules <---Why?
            └───project
                ├───backoffice
                │   └───client
                │       ├───controllers
                │       ├───css
                │       └───views
                ├───common
                ├───frontoffice
                │   └───client
                │       ├───controllers
                │       ├───css
                │       └───views
                ├───models
                └───node_modules
```

Comment: Usually node_modules refers to modules installes with npm. so Project should be on the same level. Not inside.

Comment: exactly, check my edit, I am  still totally puzzled on what he was thinking. The guy is supposed to have learned node.js from a node.js expert; and he had been a C#/Java expert for 20+ years before. Since he had 20+ years of exp while i am just 1 year exp, i was shy to ask him about it at first, I really i did ask once but he said this how he learned to do it. Very puzzling.

Comment: Maybe a trial and fail approach? difficult to say whether there was some logic.But I don't see any library that would make this structure. There is a package json file in the node directory?

Comment: no, the package.json file is inside the project directory, the libraries are being downloaded to the second node_modules (inside project folder)

Comment: There are also three git repositories, one in the project folder, one in frontoffice, and another in backoffice. But I don't think this is relevant. And oh, each of frontoffice and backoffice has its own package.json.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this file structure is, not just a bit but very strange, I'm not a professional, but I've worked a lot on node.js projects (all by my on), and I already see a lot of node.js projects from other people.

So I would say that this folder structure is really messed up. Commonly the root directory is a folder with the project's name, without special characters (including spaces), the node_modules folder is a folder JUST for node packages and it's created automatically by node when you run "npm install" for some package.

For the project files, it's more common to create a source folder in the root directory (src). I think that's a good practice, mainly if you have a lot of configuration files.

I hope this helps!